# Koan Neo.rb - calling methods from metadata

Tags: ruby

i am going through Koans logic (Neo.rb file).

I do not understand one thing. In Method Koan.meditate is called send(name) method. Parameter name contains name of evaluated method. But there is a point .. method is in one of many inhereted classes (for example: class arrays < Neo) so method should not be visible for Neo methods. But it is.

Can someone please explain me why meditate method have access to methods of inhereted classes?

Thank,

M.

---

But it is definitely vice versa @maxpleaner ..

```
class AboutAsserts < Neo::Koan
  # We shall contemplate truth by testing reality, via asserts.
  p Neo::Koan.subclasses
  def test_assert_truth
    assert true                # This should be true
  end
-------------------------
class Koan
    attr_reader :name, :failure, :koan_count, :step_count, :koan_file
    def initialize(name, koan_file=nil, koan_count=0, step_count=0)
      @name = name
      @failure = nil
      @koan_count = koan_count
      @step_count = step_count
      @koan_file = koan_file
    end

    def failed(failure)
      p "MSK FAILED"
      @failure = failure
    end
    def meditate
      setup
      begin
        send(name) # here is called child method of AboutAsserts which is called test_assert_truth
        p "send(name)"
```

If I understand correctly parent is Koan and child is AboutAsserts ... so not sure why the method is visible for parent ..

Comment: Even if the method is defined in a parent class, when it's called from a child, `self` is equal to the child. With `send(name) ` there's an implicit `self` so it could be rewritten as `self.send(name`). As I mentioned `self` can be the child. There aren't actually separate parent and child instances. The child inherits from the parent, meaning it gets all the parent's functionality _itself_.

Comment: Also, in the future, please include all relevant parts of the code needed to answer your question. I had to look up the Koan on Google and most answerers aren't going to be willing to do that. So you should copy-paste the code into your question (make sure to press the button to format it as code).

Comment: Issue is that on the code above the parent is calling child method.